# Powershell logon script, is it possible to show dialog to user or read some user input?

Tags: user-interface, powershell, login-script

So is it possible ?

I need to get some user credential to map certain network share. This share is not part of our domain and each user have different credentials.

**EDIT**

The script works fine if I run it from powershell console. 
Problem is that it doesn't show any promp or dialgo when I use it as a login script. When I log into desktop, the script starts, because it writes an debug log, but it doesn't show any dialog or promt user for input.

Comment: You're not specifying how you start the login script. It sounds to me you're using VBS to run the PowerShell console hidden (you can't hide a powershell console with powershell). If that's the case, you have to modify the VBS code to unhide it.

Comment: I'm not using VBS to start Powershell. I simply use group policy settings, on win 2008r2 you have option to use powershell script, instead of cmd or vbs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your GPO **enable** the following setting: **"Run logon scripts visible"** to ensure that the logon script is visible.
You can find it under **User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Scripts**

Comment: I have one more question if you know. I was using ISE for development of the script and there I get nice popups for user input, but at the logon time there is only console window. Is it possible to get same GUI for logon script ?

Comment: In 2012 R2 the setting name shows as "Display instructions in logon scripts as they run."

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell has a Get-Credential cmdlet that can be used to prompt for username/password. For details and examples do `Get-Help Get-Credential -Full` in PowerShell.

Comment: I wasn't explicit enough. I know this cmdlet and script works fine if I run it from powershell console. Problem is that it doesn't show any promp or dialgo when I use it as a login script. When I log into desktop, the script starts, because it writes an debug log, but it doesn't show any dialog or promt user for input.

Comment: Afraid I've never ran a PowerShell script as a login script so I don't know the differences. You could try the $host.UI.Prompt or $host.UI.PromptForCredential methods, see if they behave differently, although I suspect not. Can you get a prompt with a normal DOS script?

Comment: How can you get promp with DOS script ?

Comment: No idea to be honest, I just thought if you knew we might be able to convert it to PowerShell or spot the problem... Presumably it's something to do with when the script runs. Is the user's desktop available when the script runs?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me. It did show the credential prompt. Below is my script:

```
"test" | out-file -append C:\test.log
$cred = get-credential
$cred.username | out-file -append C:\test.log
```

Configuration of Logon script:

> gpedit.msc -> User configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts ->
>   Logon -> Choose Powershell scripts tab -> Add and enter path to script

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I do and it doesn't work for me :(  If I add "command line" column in the task manager I see that powershell process is started with parameters -ExecutionPolicy ByPass and -File MapNetDrives.ps1

Comment: @Primoz - What is you exact script?

Comment: I tried your short example and It doesn't work for me either. It seems that is something different in my enviroment.

Comment: Even if I make intentional error in the code, like writing to C:\ (which is not allowed for users) I won't see any error. I also checked that the PS process on logon runs under right account.

Answer (score 0):

I've never configured GP like this to run logon scripts so I'm not sure about this... 
If you run an arbitrary CMD like ipconfig will that pop up the console window as you're hoping PowerShell will?

If so, instead of using the built-in PowerShell script mechanism, you could call a CMD line or .bat that then calls the PowerShell script: 
powershell.exe -noexit -command "& 'path\to\logonscript.ps1'"

Answer (score 0):

With the GPO "Run logon scripts visible" the window is visible, but hidden! (At least in Windows 10).

Here it helps to have one script call another with

```
start "title" second-script.cmd /max
```

or make one script call itself, for example like this:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" (
   start "Logon" "%~dpnx0" X /max
   goto :EOF
)
rem PUT YOUR COMMANDS HERE
exit
```